# Из span в textarea

Tags: jquery, button, textarea, href

Здравствуйте. У меня есть [калькулятор](http://codepen.io/KEMPZOR/pen/NbBGbq). Какую переменную нужно дописать в скрипт, чтобы итоговая строка`<div class="calc-itogo"><span class="cena-izdeliya"></span></div>` вывелась в `<textarea name="d[2]" id="d[2]" required=""></textarea>/` по нажатию на кнопку. Помогите пожалуйста разобраться.

```
<script>
    $(function () {

        $('.form-button').on('click', function () {
               $("#d\\[2\\]").val("Johnny Bravo");
        });
    })
</script>
<a class="form-button" href="#">КНОПКА</a>
<textarea name="d[2]" id="d[2]" required=""></textarea>
```

Вот набросок ещё набросок кода.

Comment: разве вас устроит ответ «можно» (или «нельзя»)? думаю, вряд ли. потому сформулируйет, пожалуйста, полноценный вопрос, нажав [edit].